# Can't load JS file for firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, google-chrome, add-on

I have a working firefox extension that currently consists of a button. When I click that button, my XUL file declares `oncommand="test();"` which simply is an `alert("hi!");` .

I am including the file like this:

```
  <script type="application/x-javascript"
    src="chrome://myfirstextension/content/resultscollector.js" />
```

the resultscollector.js file is right where it should be in `\content` , but this does not work.

But, when I simply move the file into another extensions content folder that I am testing, and change the URL I am accessing to reflect that (`chrome://myotherfirstextension/content/resultscollector.js`) - it works!

To add to the confusion, though both extensions show up under *tools -> addons* and *view -> toolbars*, and for that matter, on the actual toolbar, I can browse to `chrome://myotherfirstextension/content/overlay.xul`, whereas an attempt to browse to myfirstextensions' overlay file fails (the locationbar simply won't allow me to press enter).

If anyone can help with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your chrome registration is wrong, take a look at [this MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Chrome_Registration)